# How to get CPU temperature and fan speed on OS X?

Tags: macos, iokit, temperature

How do I get CPU temperature and fan speeds in OS X?

I understand that information is obtained from `IOHWSensor` in `IOKit`, but I'm unable to find any reliable information on how to exactly do that.

I've found an article with a sample program - http://www.booktou.com/node/148/0321278542/ch10lev1sec7.html, but all I get with it is the GPU temperature. I'm sure there are CPU temperature sensors on the unibody Macs, so that means I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source code for this Prefpane that's called FanControl is avilable; it shows temperatures and fan speeds: http://www.lobotomo.com/products/FanControl/index.html

Answer (score 4):

If you have npm installed, there is also cli tool called **macstats**. 
You can install it using:

**`[sudo] npm install macstats -g`**

Then just run the command and it will give you output like:

```
--- CPU Stats ---
CPU Temp:        33.75°C

--- Fans Stats ---
Fan 0 speed:     1996 RPM
Fan 1 speed:     2003 RPM

--- Battery Stats ---
Charged:         82%
Capacity:        92%
Cycle Count:     692 (69%)
Max Cycle Count: 1000
Current Charge:  5189 mAh
Maximum Charge:  6316 mAh
Design Capacity: 6900 mAh
Time Remaining:  6.54 h
Temperature:     30.06°C
```

The tools also exposes API that you can use in a custom application. 
 See https://github.com/jkuri/macstats for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Fanny Widget tool provide details about your Fans condition,CPU, GPU temperature details ect. Just download opensource mac app widget.

https://www.fannywidget.com/

- It's only recommendation as per my experience.