# Programmatically read CPU temperature (+ other sensor data) on MacOSX (Macbook Pros)

Tags: macos, temperature

I'd like to programmatically read CPU temperature + any other interesting sensor data from my MacBook Pro (2009 model).

How do I do it?

I noticed a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216888/how-to-get-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-on-osx) pointing to [this open source software](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/FanControl/index.html), but it seems to be incompatible with my model.

I notice that there are numerous apps which are able to do it, so it must be possible!

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?
This is exactly what I am looking to do right now.

Comment: No unfortunately not.  Please let me know if you do!

Comment: I had similar results, when I look for IOHWSensor on a new mac pro -- the entire system tree is displayed and there are no IOHWSensor lines displayed.

Comment: Still no luck with this?

Answer (score 4):

I found this opensource that maybe help you on the idea of how to do it (it's newer than your reference).
https://github.com/lavoiesl/osx-cpu-temp

Comment: Fantastic - will try it out….