# Getting CPU temperature in macOS Swift App

Tags: swift, macos, iokit

I am building an external cooling fan controller and I need to read the CPU temperature in my Swift app.

For this purpose, I applied the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875104/macos-how-to-get-cpu-temperature-programmatically) thread and I managed to read the temperatures in a *Swift Command Line Tool* but when I try to do the exact same thing in a *Swift App* I get this output when I call SMCOpen():

Error: IOServiceOpen() = e00002e2

At first, I thought it was because of my info.plist file but modifying it (according to the aforementioned thread) did not solve the problem and I could not find any workarounds. Is there a solution to this problem?

P.S. I am fairly new to Swift programming and SMCOpen() method is called in Appdelegate.swift

Edit: This app will be personal use only, you can disregard App Store policies.

Comment: Is it a sandboxed app ?

Comment: I did not explicitly sandbox it, i.e., info.plist does not have a sandbox key(but I tried adding it and setting it to true and false and nothing changed for both cases) but I do not know the default behavior.