# temperature was not able to be retrieved

Tags: swift, iokit

I am building a simple macOS menu bar app in swift that displays my machine's CPU temperature
and I'm just testing out my function to make sure it can retrieve the temp and display it in the Xcode terminal but instead my error handler messages are triggered indicating an issue retrieving my machines CPU temp data

"CPU temp °F could not be retrieved
temps couldnot be displayed"

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import IOKit
import IOKit.ps


class CPUTempWithServiceMatching {
    
    static func getCPUTemp() -> Double? {
        
        let dictionaryMatching = IOServiceMatching("AppleSMC")
        
        var service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMainPortDefault, dictionaryMatching)
        
        var temp = "0.0"
        
        if service != 0 {
            
            let key = "TC0P"   //thermal zone zero proxy
            
            if let result = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, key as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0 ) {
                temp = (result.takeUnretainedValue() as! NSNumber).doubleValue.description
                IOObjectRelease(service)
                
                if let CPUTemp = Double(temp) {
                    print("CPU Temp: \(CPUTemp) °F")
                    return(CPUTemp)
                }
            }
            print("CPU temp °F could not be retrieved")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
  @main
struct program {
   static func main() {
        if let cpuTemp = CPUTempWithServiceMatching.getCPUTemp() {
            print("cpu temp\(cpuTemp) °F")
        } else {
            print("temps couldnot be displayed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [macOS. How to get CPU temperature programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875104/macos-how-to-get-cpu-temperature-programmatically)

Comment: Yes thank you :)