# Query system stats on OS X

Tags: c++, c, macos, unix, kernel-extension

So I've checked in the past, and I could not find any information so I let it rest. I'm curious what OS X APIs are called in apps like iStat Menu or other system information apps? I could not find what functions  to call to get CPU temp or fan speeds. Are these kexts or very specific Unix system calls? I would be very grateful for anyone with insight!

Comment: Is [How to get cpu temperature and fan speed on osx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216888/how-to-get-cpu-temperature-and-fan-speed-on-osx) out of date then?

Comment: And googling `os x read fan speed site:stackoverflow.com` returns 1000 results

Comment: Oh thank you! I did not see that when I previously searched! Perfect!

Comment: I didn't actually know you could pass Google arguments specifying site? In the past when I queried I never got any useful information. Thanks for the tip